# Check consecutive working days in attendance plan

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, odoo-11

I have an attendance plan for employees. Every employee must enter their project time every day in the project management tool, which is integrated with the attendance sheet (`has_pm_entry`). If any employee does not give their time in three consecutive working days (`status=='Working Day'`). He/she will be counted as one day absent and the status of the first day in three consecutive days will be `Absent`.

A cron job will run everyday night at 11 PM.

**Example:**

**employee 1**, doesn't have pm_entry in `01/03/2019, 01/04/2019, and 01/08/2019`. So, the status of `01/03/2019` will be `'Absent'` according to the rule. (`01/05/2019, 01/06/2019, and 01/07/2019` will not count. Because their status is not working day).

The data is shown only for one employee, but **the operation will be for more than a thousand employees**.

Now, my question is, how can I achieve this in an efficient way.

DB: `Postgresql`, Language: `Python`, ORM: `Odoo ORM`

Here is the excel attendance sheet link for the overview of my database structure https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C1ZEds1-mTFpRlVo0mf1IA642xqfuybGRNkpDdsVYGw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: That spreadsheet requires some sort of acess/permission to view.

Comment: Done, please check again

Comment: It works, I can access it.

Comment: Could you please narrow your problem to something more specific? Like for example "I did this SQL, it works most of the time but not on holidays. How can I make it to work with additional non working days?" or "I did this SQL, it gives me expected output, but works really slow. Here is EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output."